# Bootstrap DataTable doesn't work as described in plugin docs

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm struggling to create a DataTable in Bootstrap. I followed exactly the steps mention in the plugin documentation, which can be found at the link https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4, but doesn't work. The table is displayed whithout sorting, search, paging.

Please help. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you, 
Anamaria

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>DataTable</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Table example</h4>
                <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">Bootstrap datatable</h6>
                <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Cell 2</td>
                                <td>Cell 3</td>
                                <td>Cell 4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the sequencing of JS files you have loaded.

It has to be:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

As bootstrap needs jQuery and DataTables also needs jQuery, so it must be loaded first.

If you will load it later, it would result in error.

So, your complete code should work as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>DataTable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Table example</h4>
                <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">Bootstrap datatable</h6>
                <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cell 1</td>
                                <td>Cell 2</td>
                                <td>Cell 3</td>
                                <td>Cell 4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```